# changing chrome's dialogue that asks for audio permissions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-audio-api, getusermedia

I'm making a web app that calls getUserMedia in chrome and asks for a user's permission. this is the default dialogue that pops down beneath the url/favorites area:

http://f.cl.ly/items/1Y423q3Z0F3a2c0D1T0N/Screen%20Shot%202013-07-01%20at%207.42.43%20PM.png

is there anyway to customize this to be an alert or dialogue, rather than the default?

Comment: Probably not (security reasons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot change the behavior for requesting permission in Chrome.